# What is the best way to beat the nougat monster in candy box two WITHOUT using rocket boots?

Tags: candy-box-2

I have jumped on him till he dies, but that is only a one in ten chance of working? What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can beat it with boots of introspection, octopus crown with jaspers,red glove, and the enchanted monkey wizard staff. you start off by not moving, drinking a beserker potion,and then casting the black demons spell repeatedly until he is almost on top of you, then jump forward repeatedly but land on the nougat monster until he dies.